# How to generate a font image used in Android power-off charging animation?

Tags: android

Android power-off charging animation use recovery UI, but if I want to display texture, it should be invoke "gr_init_font()", which need a "font.png" to init font.

I have no idea which tool can make font.png.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Answer it myself, a python script, Roboto-Regular.ttf,  Roboto-Boldttf  to generate Roboto.png:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
import os



def draw_png(name, font_size = 40):
    font_reg  = ImageFont.truetype(name + '-Regular' + '.ttf', font_size)
    font_bold = ImageFont.truetype(name + '-Bold' + '.ttf', font_size)
    text=r''' !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~'''
    text_width, text_height = font_bold.getsize(text)

max_w = 0
max_h = 0
for c in text:
    w, h = font_bold.getsize(c)
    if w > max_w:
        max_w = w
        
    if h > max_h:
        max_h = h
     
print max_w, max_h

image = Image.new(mode='RGB', size=(max_w*96, max_h*2))
draw_table = ImageDraw.Draw(im=image)
i = 0
for c in text:
    text_width, text_height = font_bold.getsize(c)
    print c , text_width, text_height
    draw_table.text(xy=(max_w*i, 0), text=c, fill='#ffffff', font=font_reg, anchor="mm", align="center")
    draw_table.text(xy=(max_w*i, max_h), text=c, fill='#ffffff', font=font_bold, anchor="mm",align="center")
    i = i + 1

image.show()
image.save( name + '.png', 'PNG')
image.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print('running:')
    try:
        draw_png('Roboto')
    except Exception as e:
        print( ' ERR: ', e)
```